# Typecasting interface to a class object in c#

Tags: c#

I wanted to know if the below typecasting I am doing is correct or not ?

```
 Interface IA 
{
      string AName {get;set;}
      string A_Address {get;set;} 
      UpdateA_Address();
}
 Interface IB 
{
      string BName {get;set;}
      string B_Address {get;set;} 
      UpdateB_Address();
}
public class A : IA
{
    ///implemented both prop
    public void MethodNotInterfaceA()
    {
       //Some stuff
    }
}
public class B : IB
{
    ///implemented both prop
    public void MethodNotInterfaceB()
    {
       //Some stuff
    }   
}
public class X
{
   IA aObj {get;set;}
   IB bObj {get;set;}

   public x()
   {
    aObj = new A();
    bObj = new B();          
   }

   public void SomeMethod1()
   {
      //some stuff here
      aObj.UpdateB_Address();
      aobj.MethodNotInterfaceB(); =============> is telling method not impemeted not part of interface
      (aObj as A).MethodNotInterfaceB(); =============> this casting an interface to an class type is valid
   }

   public void SomeMethod2()
   {
      //some stuff here
      bObj.UpdateB_Address(); 
      bObj.MethodNotInterfaceB(); =============> is telling method not impemeted not part of interface
      (bObj as B).MethodNotInterfaceB(); =============> this casting an interface to an class type is valid
   }
}
```

These interfaces are common to other classes hence the  MethodNotInterfaceB() is not part of it and I want to access this in class X so am converting into a class object from interface type.

Can you please let me know if this is valid and error handling do i need take care while typecasting.

FYI --- it is building without any errors and working `enter code here`fine also

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: Whenever I see code that has to cast an interface to a specific implementation, it raises a red flag for me.  Ideally when you are working with an interface, you want to be carefree with the wind in your hair, no thoughts about implementation details at all.

Comment: when you use interface, so then you can call only method in this interface. MethodNotInterfaceB is not define in IB